# MongoError: Field name duplication not allowed with modifiers

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Note: I am not doing the push-pop thing, as far as I know.

I have this which works fine the first time, but if the client calls this method twice without refreshing the page in-between calls, I'll get the error in the title.

```
scenarios.findOne({'_id':partialUpdate._id},function(err,back){

            if(back){
                for(var p in partialUpdate){
                    if(partialUpdate.hasOwnProperty(p)){
                        back[p] = partialUpdate[p];
                    }
                }
                back.save(function(err,product,numberAffected){...
```

What is it about refreshing the page that stops this error from happening?
How can I tell which field name I'm duplicating so I can stop this error?

Here's a copy of the server output that contains the first and second sets of sent data (`partialData`), the server data it merges with (`back`), and the saved data (`product`), and the error message

http://pastebin.com/izbkZV1h

First set of sent object:

```
{ sortOrder: 0,
  title: 'sdfsdf',
  description: '',
  contentType: 'false',
  _id: '534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee1c',
  __v: 8,
  groupSharing: [],
  sharingWith: [],
  isPublic: false,
  content: false,
  attributes: [],
  metrics:
   [ { type: 'viewCount',
       value: '1',
       metric: 'Viewed',
       _id: '534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee1e',
       createDate: '2014-04-16T18:02:49.454Z' },
     { type: 'playCount',
       value: '1',
       metric: 'Played',
       _id: '534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee1d',
       createDate: '2014-04-16T18:02:49.453Z' } ],
  bundleId: [],
  video:
   [ { videoLocation: 'rtmp://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/vid_51323386'
,
       thumbnailLocation: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/thumb_51323386.
png',
       _id: '534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee20',
       createDate: '2014-04-16T18:02:49.457Z',
       format: 'FLV' } ],
  display: true,
  active: true,
  createDate: '2014-04-16T18:02:49.000Z',
  revision: 1,
  scripts:
   [ { _id: '534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee1f',
       display: true,
       active: true,
       createDate: '2014-04-16T18:02:49.454Z',
       keyPoints: [],
       body: [Object],
       subject: [] } ],
  presentation:
   [ { pageLocation: null,
       _id: '534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee21',
       display: true,
       active: true,
       syncManifest: [],
       pageNumber: [Object] } ],
  subcategoryId: [ '53236dff2ab8b9182716f34d' ],
  categoryId: [ '532369bb2ab8b9182716f33d' ],
  authorId: [ '532c9a146ce0682319cebbf9' ] }
```

Object on the server it's supposed to overwrite:

```
 { sortOrder: 0,
  title: 'sdfsdf',
  description: '',
  contentType: 'false',
  _id: 534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee1c,
  __v: 8,
  groupSharing: [],
  sharingWith: [],
  isPublic: false,
  content: false,
  attributes: [],
  metrics:
   [ { type: 'viewCount',
       value: '1',
       metric: 'Viewed',
       _id: 534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee1e,
       createDate: Wed Apr 16 2014 12:02:49 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) },

     { type: 'playCount',
       value: '1',
       metric: 'Played',
       _id: 534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee1d,
       createDate: Wed Apr 16 2014 12:02:49 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) }
],
  bundleId: [],
  video:
   [ { videoLocation: 'rtmp://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/vid_51323386'
,
       thumbnailLocation: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxcloudfront.net/thumb_51323386.
png',
       _id: 534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee20,
       createDate: Wed Apr 16 2014 12:02:49 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time),
       format: 'FLV' } ],
  display: true,
  active: true,
  createDate: Wed Apr 16 2014 12:02:49 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time),
  revision: 1,
  scripts:
   [ { _id: 534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee1f,
       display: true,
       active: true,
       createDate: Wed Apr 16 2014 12:02:49 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time),
       keyPoints: [],
       body: [Object],
       subject: [] } ],
  presentation:
   [ { pageLocation: null,
       _id: 534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee21,
       display: true,
       active: true,
       syncManifest: [],
       pageNumber: [Object] } ],
  subcategoryId: [ 53236d392ab8b9182716f341 ],
  categoryId: [ 532368bc2ab8b9182716f339 ],
  authorId: [ 532c9a146ce0682319cebbf9 ] }
```

Resulting object:

```
    { sortOrder: 0,
  title: 'sdfsdf',
  description: '',
  contentType: 'false',
  _id: 534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee1c,
  __v: 9,
  groupSharing: [],
  sharingWith: [],
  isPublic: false,
  content: false,
  attributes: [],
  metrics:
   [ { type: 'viewCount',
       value: '1',
       metric: 'Viewed',
       _id: 534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee1e,
       createDate: Wed Apr 16 2014 12:02:49 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) },

     { type: 'playCount',
       value: '1',
       metric: 'Played',
       _id: 534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee1d,
       createDate: Wed Apr 16 2014 12:02:49 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) }
],
  bundleId: [],
  video:
   [ { videoLocation: 'rtmp://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/vid_51323386'
,
       thumbnailLocation: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/thumb_51323386.
png',
       _id: 534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee20,
       createDate: Wed Apr 16 2014 12:02:49 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time),
       format: 'FLV' } ],
  display: true,
  active: true,
  createDate: Wed Apr 16 2014 12:02:49 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time),
  revision: 1,
  scripts:
   [ { _id: 534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee1f,
       display: true,
       active: true,
       createDate: Wed Apr 16 2014 12:02:49 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time),
       keyPoints: [],
       body: [Object],
       subject: [] } ],
  presentation:
   [ { pageLocation: null,
       _id: 534ec5c98c4bf1be305fee21,
       display: true,
       active: true,
       syncManifest: [],
       pageNumber: [Object] } ],
  subcategoryId: [ 53236dff2ab8b9182716f34d ],
  categoryId: [ 532369bb2ab8b9182716f33d ],
  authorId: [ 532c9a146ce0682319cebbf9 ] }
```

One difference I notice is that instead of sending it an array of ObjectIDs, I send it an array of strings, and instead of a date like `Wed Apr 16 2014 12:02:49 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)` I'm sending it `2014-04-16T18:02:49.454Z`. Would that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1933

I was explicitly saving the `__v` property, which is a no-no.

In my loop, I just checked to see if `p` was equal to `__v`, and if it was, I would ignore it. No more problem.

Comment: From the github link: add this to your Schema(s): `__v: {type: Number, select: false}`